# FBGraph Login page issue with "done" and "login" button

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, fb-graph

I am using FBGraph to get user's friends list in my application, After entering user credentials in login page of FaceBook, when I tap "Done" button in keyboard and tap again on "login Facebook" button it is moving to user profile page in webview.

My requirement is after successful login in FaceBook ,the webview has to dismiss and open user's friends list in tableview.

I have reached my requirement if I tap anyone of these two buttons but I need the same output when I tap two buttons simultaneously.

now the output screen shot is as shown in the below attachment.

[image]